# Disposed DirectoryWatcher in VS2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on a asp.net application and connected a ADO Data Entity Item. However, once I have it created I get "Cannot load C:\users.....\RealEstateFirmEDM.edmx Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'DirectoryWatcher'"

What is going on here, I did not modify anything in the core of the app. Left it as is and the database if functional.

[image]

Comment: There is no way we can possibly answer this without seeing your code.

Comment: Open the source code (in notepad if necessary). What files are using `DirectoryWatcher`?

Comment: Okay so which bit of source code? I'm all new to this and the only code we modified in class was the _layout.cshtml to changed the copywrite on the application.